# How to pass an object's variable stored as java's Object to another object's Function which is also stored as java's Object?

Tags: java, object, libgdx, bulletphysics

I am trying to make collision detector in Libgdx using Bullet. Here I want pass one colliding object's `power` variable as parameter to another object's `onCollision()` function. Here `Ball` and `Brick` extend `AbstractObject`. Also `power` and `onCollision()` is declared in `AbstractObject` but initialized in `Brick` and `Ball`. I have set `btCollisionObject.userData=this` in each class.What is the most efficient way to do this?
Here is my current contactListener:

```
package com.anutrix.brickbreaker3d.Helpers;

import com.anutrix.brickbreaker3d.gameObjects.AbstractObject;
import com.anutrix.brickbreaker3d.gameObjects.Ball;
import com.anutrix.brickbreaker3d.gameObjects.Brick;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g3d.ModelInstance;
import com.badlogic.gdx.physics.bullet.collision.ContactListener;
import com.badlogic.gdx.physics.bullet.collision.btCollisionObject;
import com.badlogic.gdx.utils.Array;

public class CollisionListener extends ContactListener {

    @Override
    public boolean onContactAdded(btCollisionObject ob0, int partId0, int index0, btCollisionObject ob1, int partId1, int index1) {

        Gdx.app.log("sdkjg", "fsfgsdg");
        Ball bl = null;
        Brick br = null;
        AbstractObject aO0 = (AbstractObject) ob0.userData;
        AbstractObject aO1 = (AbstractObject) ob1.userData;
        if (aO0 instanceof Ball) {
            bl = (Ball) aO0;
        } else if (aO1 instanceof Ball) {
            bl = (Ball) aO1;
        }

        if (aO0 instanceof Brick) {
            br = (Brick) aO0;
        } else if (aO1 instanceof Brick) {
            br = (Brick) aO1;
        }
        bl.onCollision(br.power);
        br.onCollision(bl.power);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Here is the `Ball` Class:

```
public class Ball extends AbstractObject {

    public Integer power;

    public Ball(Integer id, Integer type, Vector3 position) {
        super(id, type, position);
        modelInstance = new ModelInstance(Assets.instance.ball.get(type));
        shape = new btSphereShape(0.2f);
        body = new btCollisionObject();
        body.setCollisionShape(shape);
        super.setPosition(position);
        this.power = type + 1;
        this.body.setCollisionFlags(this.body.getCollisionFlags() | btCollisionObject.CollisionFlags.CF_CUSTOM_MATERIAL_CALLBACK);
        active=true;
        body.userData=this;
    }

    public Integer getPower() {
        return power;
    }

    public void resetPower() {
        this.power = this.getType()+1;
    }

    public void onCollision(Integer power) {
        this.collided=true;
    }

    @Override
    public void getDetails(){
        Gdx.app.log("Life", power.toString());
        Gdx.app.log("Active", Boolean.toString(this.active));
        super.getDetails();
    }
}
```

Here is Brick class:

```
package com.anutrix.brickbreaker3d.gameObjects;

import com.anutrix.brickbreaker3d.Helpers.Assets;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g3d.ModelInstance;
import com.badlogic.gdx.math.Vector3;
import com.badlogic.gdx.physics.bullet.collision.btBoxShape;
import com.badlogic.gdx.physics.bullet.collision.btCollisionObject;

/**
 *
 * @author Anutrix
 */
public class Brick extends AbstractObject {

    public Integer power;

    public Brick(Integer id, Integer type, Vector3 position) {
        super(id, type, position);
        modelInstance = new ModelInstance(Assets.instance.brick.get(type));
        shape = new btBoxShape(new Vector3(1f, 0.5f, 1f));
        body = new btCollisionObject();
        body.setCollisionShape(shape);
        super.setPosition(position);
        this.power = type + 1;
        this.body.setCollisionFlags(this.body.getCollisionFlags() | btCollisionObject.CollisionFlags.CF_CUSTOM_MATERIAL_CALLBACK);
        active=true;
        body.userData=this;
    }

    public Integer getPower() {
        return power;
    }

    public void onCollision(Integer power) {
        this.power = this.power-power;
        if(this.power<=0){
            this.active=false;
        }
        this.collided=false;//reset 
    }

    @Override
    public void getDetails(){
        Gdx.app.log("Life", power.toString());
        Gdx.app.log("Active", Boolean.toString(this.active));
        super.getDetails();
    }
}
```

Here is AbstractObject Class:

```
package com.anutrix.brickbreaker3d.gameObjects;

import com.anutrix.brickbreaker3d.Helpers.Assets;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g3d.ModelInstance;
import com.badlogic.gdx.math.Vector3;
import com.badlogic.gdx.physics.bullet.collision.btCollisionObject;
import com.badlogic.gdx.physics.bullet.collision.btCollisionShape;

public class AbstractObject {

    private Integer id;
    private Integer type;
    private Vector3 position;

    public ModelInstance modelInstance;

    public btCollisionShape shape;
    public btCollisionObject body;
    public Integer power;
    public boolean collided;
    public boolean active;

    public AbstractObject(Integer id, Integer type, Vector3 position) {
        this.id = id;
        this.type = type;
        this.position = position;
        this.collided = false;
    }

    public void setPosition(float x, float y, float z) {
        this.setPosition(new Vector3(x, y, z));
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Integer getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(Integer type) {
        this.type = type;
        this.setModelInstance(new ModelInstance(Assets.instance.brick.get(type)));
    }

    public Vector3 getPosition() {
        return position;
    }

    public void setPosition(Vector3 position) {
        this.position = position;
        this.modelInstance.transform.translate(position);
        this.body.setWorldTransform(modelInstance.transform);
    }

    public ModelInstance getModelInstance() {
        return modelInstance;
    }

    public void setModelInstance(ModelInstance modelInstance) {
        this.modelInstance = modelInstance;
    }

    public btCollisionObject getObject() {
        return body;
    }

    public void onCollision(Integer power){

    }

    public void getDetails() {
        Gdx.app.log("ID", id.toString());
        Gdx.app.log("Type", type.toString());
        Gdx.app.log("Position", position.toString());
        Gdx.app.log("Collision", Boolean.toString(collided));
        Gdx.app.log("---------------", "---------------");
    }

    public void dispose() {
        shape.dispose();
        body.dispose();
        Gdx.app.log(this.toString(), "dispose");
    }
}
```

Is there an alternative to all that casting? Casting decreases performance right?

Comment: Please post the code for `Ball` and `Brick`, and explain what's wrong with your current code

Comment: I don't believe you need the second if block (assuming that both objects are always different) the else if could swapped for a plain else also

Comment: I would use an abstract `onCollision(int)` and `getPower()` in `AbstractObject`

Comment: @RC You removed one round of casting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think what you hit is kind of a classical problem in OOP design in mainstream modern languages i.e. lack of [multiple dispatch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_dispatch) or [multimethods](http://wiki.c2.com/?MultiMethods). There are a few typical ways to fight it and the most traditional one uses [double dispatch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_dispatch) and optionally a [visitor pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern).

General idea looks something like this

```java
public abstract class AbstractObject {

    ...
    
    public final void dispatchCollision(AbstractObject other) {
        other.dispatchCollisionImpl(this);
    }

    protected abstract void dispatchCollisionImpl(AbstractObject other);

    protected abstract void onCollisionWithBall(Ball ball);

    protected abstract void onCollisionWithBrick(Brick ball);
}


public class Ball extends AbstractObject {

    ...
    
    @Override
    protected void dispatchCollisionImpl(AbstractObject other) {
        other.onCollisionWithBall(this); // this is where main "magic" happens
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCollisionWithBall(Ball ball) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Ball-ball collision should never happen");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCollisionWithBrick(Brick ball) {
        // your actual brick-ball collision logic
    }

}
```

Code in the `Brick` class is pretty symmetrical to the code in the `Ball`.

And then in your `CollisionListener` you can simply do something like:

```java
public class CollisionListener extends ContactListener {

    @Override
    public boolean onContactAdded(btCollisionObject ob0, int partId0, int index0, btCollisionObject ob1, int partId1, int index1) {
        AbstractObject aO0 = (AbstractObject) ob0.userData;
        AbstractObject aO1 = (AbstractObject) ob1.userData;

        aO0.dispatchCollision(aO1);
        //aO1.dispatchCollision(aO0); // if you want to do both

        return true;
    }
}
```

The main drawback of this approach is that if you have many subclasses of your `AbstractObject`, you need to add methods for each of them in each subclass. On the other hand you can put some default generic logic to such methods in some base classes.

If you have many subclasses or need some plugin-like support you should probably go to more advanced techniques for multi-methods simulation such as for example having explicit global `Map<Tuple<Class,Class>, Handler>` for dispatch.

---

**Explicit Multi-methods**

Here is one idea on how to create something similar to multi-methods more explicitly:

```java
public class ClassesPair {
    public final Class<? extends AbstractObject> targetClass;
    public final Class<? extends AbstractObject> objectClass;

    public ClassesPair(Class<? extends AbstractObject> targetClass, Class<? extends AbstractObject> objectClass) {
        this.targetClass = targetClass;
        this.objectClass = objectClass;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

        ClassesPair that = (ClassesPair) o;

        if (!targetClass.equals(that.targetClass)) return false;
        return objectClass.equals(that.objectClass);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int result = targetClass.hashCode();
        result = 31 * result + objectClass.hashCode();
        return result;
    }
}

public interface CollisionHandler<T extends AbstractObject, O extends AbstractObject> {
    void handleCollision(T target, O object);
}

public class CollisionsDispatcher {
    private final Map<ClassesPair, CollisionHandler> originalDispatchMap = new HashMap<>();
    private Map<ClassesPair, CollisionHandler> extendedDispatchMap = new HashMap<>();

    private CollisionHandler getHandlerOrParent(Class<? extends AbstractObject> targetClass, Class<? extends AbstractObject> objectClass) {
        //Need to decide on the rules, for now target is more important
        Class stopClass = AbstractObject.class.getSuperclass();
        for (Class tmpTarget = targetClass; tmpTarget != stopClass; tmpTarget = tmpTarget.getSuperclass()) {
            for (Class tmpObject = objectClass; tmpObject != stopClass; tmpObject = tmpObject.getSuperclass()) {
                CollisionHandler collisionHandler = originalDispatchMap.get(new ClassesPair(tmpTarget, tmpObject));
                if (collisionHandler != null)
                    return collisionHandler;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    public CollisionHandler getHandler(Class<? extends AbstractObject> targetClass, Class<? extends AbstractObject> objectClass) {
        ClassesPair key = new ClassesPair(targetClass, objectClass);
        CollisionHandler collisionHandler = extendedDispatchMap.get(key);
        if (collisionHandler == null) {

            // choice #1
            // Just fail every time nothing was found
            //throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Collision of " + targetClass.getName() + " with " + objectClass.getName() + "' is not supported");

            // choice #2 go through handlers for parents.
            // It provides ability to put some generic logic only once
            // Need to decide on the rules, for now target is more important
            collisionHandler = getHandlerOrParent(targetClass, objectClass);
            if (collisionHandler != null) {
                extendedDispatchMap.put(key, collisionHandler); // put it back for faster future usages
            } else {
                throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Collision of " + targetClass.getName() + " with " + objectClass.getName() + "' is not supported");
            }

            // choice #3
            // Just do nothing. Everything that has no explicit handler is not affected by collision
            // return null;
        }
        return collisionHandler; // God save Java with its type erasure for generics!
    }

    public void handleCollision(AbstractObject target, AbstractObject object) {
        CollisionHandler handler = getHandler(target.getClass(), object.getClass());
        if (handler != null) { // this check only for choice #3
            handler.handleCollision(target, object); // God save Java with its type erasure for generics!
        }
    }

    public <T extends AbstractObject, O extends AbstractObject> void registerHandler(Class<T> targetClass, Class<O> objectClass, CollisionHandler<? super T, ? super O> handler) {
        ClassesPair key = new ClassesPair(targetClass, objectClass);
        originalDispatchMap.put(key, handler);
        // just clear extended cache. It is much easier than to track all possible propagated values
        // and handle them properly. On the other hand registerHandler should be called only a few
        // time during set up so it shouldn't be real penalty in performance
        extendedDispatchMap = new HashMap<>();
    }
}
```

So now for an usage example assume that you want to create some Arkanoid-like game with 3 kinds of bricks:

- one-hit brick which is always blue
- two-hits brick that changes color from red to pink after first hit
- super-brick that is black and can not be destroyed at all

```java
public abstract class AbstractBrick extends AbstractObject {

    protected int hitCount;

    public AbstractBrick(int hitCount) {
        this.hitCount = hitCount;
    }

    public int getHitCount() {
        return hitCount;
    }

    public void setHitCount(int hitCount) {
        this.hitCount = hitCount;
    }

    public abstract Color getColor();

    @Override
    protected void dispatchCollisionImpl(AbstractObject other) {
        other.onCollisionWithBrick(this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCollisionWithBall(Ball ball) {

    }

    @Override
    protected void onCollisionWithBrick(AbstractBrick ball) {

    }

}

// takes one hit to break
public class SimpleBrick extends AbstractBrick {
    public SimpleBrick() {
        super(1);
    }

    @Override
    public Color getColor() {
        return Color.BLUE;
    }
}

// takes two hits to break
public class DoubleBrick extends AbstractBrick {
    public DoubleBrick() {
        super(2);
    }

    @Override
    public Color getColor() {
        if (hitCount == 2)
            return Color.RED;
        else
            return Color.PINK;
    }
}

// never breaks
public class SuperBrick extends AbstractBrick {
    public SuperBrick() {
        super(-1);
    }

    @Override
    public Color getColor() {
        return Color.BLACK;
    }
}
```

So now you create specific instance of `CollisionsDispatcher` with all the necessary handlers registered in it

```java
public class MyCollisionsDispatcher extends CollisionsDispatcher {

    public MyCollisionsDispatcher() {
        // Pre-register all required handlers
        // using Java-8 syntax for "::" instead of anonymous classes
        registerHandler(Ball.class, AbstractBrick.class, this::handleBallBrick);
        registerHandler(AbstractBrick.class, Ball.class, this::handleUsualBrickBall);
        registerHandler(SuperBrick.class, Ball.class, this::handleSuperBrickBall);
    }

    void handleBallBrick(Ball ball, AbstractBrick brick) {
        // bounce of the ball
        // in this case it is not important which brick we hit
        System.out.println("Ball hit some brick");
    }

    void handleUsualBrickBall(AbstractBrick brick, Ball ball) {
        int newCount = brick.getHitCount() - 1;
        if (newCount != 0) {
            brick.setHitCount(newCount);
        } else {
            // remove brick
        }

        System.out.println("Usual brick was hit by a ball. newCount =  " + newCount);
    }

    void handleSuperBrickBall(SuperBrick brick, Ball ball) {
        // do nothing. Super brick is so super!
        System.out.println("Super brick was hit by a ball but nothing happened");
    }
}
```

and with that you can do something like this:

```java
public void test() {
    AbstractObject simpleBrick = new SimpleBrick();
    AbstractObject doubleBrick = new DoubleBrick();
    AbstractObject superBrick = new SuperBrick();
    AbstractObject ball = new Ball();

    CollisionsDispatcher dispatcher = new MyCollisionsDispatcher();

    dispatcher.handleCollision(ball, simpleBrick);
    dispatcher.handleCollision(simpleBrick, ball);

    dispatcher.handleCollision(ball, doubleBrick);
    dispatcher.handleCollision(doubleBrick, ball);
    dispatcher.handleCollision(doubleBrick, ball);

    dispatcher.handleCollision(ball, superBrick);
    dispatcher.handleCollision(superBrick, ball);
    dispatcher.handleCollision(superBrick, ball);
}
```

and the output is exactly like one would expect:

> Ball hit some brick
>
> Usual brick was hit by a ball. newCount =  0
>
> Ball hit some brick
>
> Usual brick was hit by a ball. newCount =  1
>
> Usual brick was hit by a ball. newCount =  0
>
> Ball hit some brick
>
> Super brick was hit by a ball but nothing happened
>
> Super brick was hit by a ball but nothing happened

So in your `CollisionListener` you can call just

```java
@Override
public boolean onContactAdded(btCollisionObject ob0, int partId0, int index0, btCollisionObject ob1, int partId1, int index1) {
    AbstractObject aO0 = (AbstractObject) ob0.userData;
    AbstractObject aO1 = (AbstractObject) ob1.userData;


    dispatcher.handleCollision(aO0, aO1);
    // dispatcher.handleCollision(aO1, aO0); // if you want to do both

    return true;
}
```

The main drawbacks here are the other sides of the main advantages:

- you can put all your collision-related code in a single place `MyCollisionsDispatcher` but that "single place" might get pretty big.
- Another bonus is that with such approach you might have a "plug-in" system i.e. someone can add a new `AbstractObject` subclass without touching anything in the existing code by just registering proper handlers in the dispatcher. The disadvantage of this is that in any mainstream language I know you loose your compile time checks that every necessary handler is actually implemented as it is in double-dispatch.

**Summary** (and a bit of comparison)

In terms of  long term management and code clarity it is in my opinion a matter of taste which solution to prefer unless you have other limitations which make some of them not applicable. Every suitable technique is relatively advanced and might stumble a developer how is not aware of it.

In terms of performance the first rules is: **Measure it!**. Still I'll break it and do my forecast that double dispatch is faster then explicit Map which is faster than a bunch of `instanceof` if there are many subclasses (still, YMMV) As for memory consumption I don't see any significant differences.

As someone said [Software Engineering Is Art Of Compromise](http://wiki.c2.com/?SoftwareEngineeringIsArtOfCompromise) so finally it is up to you to make right trade-offs.

Comment: I am going to create more subclasses soon. So like you said one more method per subclass in each subclass will make program much larger. Besides your "magic" code won't be clear on first sight. Can you also give the general idea of the more advanced method? It may help.

Comment: @Anutrix, I didn't get your last comment about different naming at all. The basic idea of double dispatch is following: 1. Call enters non-virtual `AbstractObject.dispatchCollision` 2. `dispatchCollision` delegates it to a virtual `dispatchCollisionImpl` and by this moment we (runtime) know the class of original `other` so it calls method specific to that class. 3. `dispatchCollisionImpl` switches arguments again and calls another virtual method that has known parameter type. At this point both types are known so proper method of the proper subclass is called.

Comment: @Anutrix, As for more general idea, the crucial questions are: 1. How many different kinds of collision behavior depending on object types you have? 2. Where do you want the code for each such different behavior to resist? Assume there are 10 different types of objects. It means you potentially have 100 = 10*10 types of collisions and each potentially has own logic. Where in code do you want those 100 pieces of logic to be?

Comment: Sorry I take my comment back . My mistake . I missed the final function. Also sorry for bad English.

Comment: I want each subclass to have different behavior to different object. I now have two choices: double dispatching or using instanceof in if conditions inside each subclass's onCollision function. Which is better based on efficiency, long term management, code clarity, processing speed and memory usage.

Comment: @Anutrix, see my update with some code fro Explicit Multi-methods